# Can RSAT-ADDS be safely removed after Exchange 2019 installation on Windows 2019 Core?

Tags: active-directory, exchange, windows-server-core, windows-server-2019, exchange-2019

I'm deploying a new Exchange Server 2019 and using Windows Server 2019 Core as basis.

Accordingly to Microsoft documentation, located https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Exchange-Team-Blog/Deploy-Exchange-Server-2019-on-Windows-Server-Core/ba-p/608269, RSAT-ADDS must be installed for the `/PrepareAD` phase of deployment.

After the deployment can RSAT-ADDS be safely removed from the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RSAT-ADDS can be removed but it is not recommended to do that. For your reference, https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/plan-and-deploy/prerequisites?view=exchserver-2019

Comment: So, did you finally get it safely removed?